# More efficient way using Linq? (CRUD operation)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Is there a more efficient way of doing the following operation

```
var admin = //linq to get admin
List<Query> userQueries = db.Queries.Where(x=> x.User == user).ToList();
    foreach (var item in userQueries)
    {
        if(!item.PrivateQuery)
        {
            var vm = new Query();
            item.Id = vm.Id;
            item.Name = vm.Name;
            item.PrivateQuery = vm.PrivateQuery;
            item.Sql = vm.Sql;
            item.User = admin;
        }

        db.Queries.Remove(item);
    }
```

I'm new to LINQ and find myself coding the following fairly often. I'm wondering if there is a more effective way of completing the same operation?

Comment: It is unclear what are you trying to do with this code.

Comment: I agree.  The code inside the if block is perplexing.

Comment: It looks like you are getting a list of Queries from the DB, and then replacing five of the properties with default values (if it's not private), and then deleting them no matter what?  What is the purpose here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty sure you can alter it to this effect.

```
List<Query> userQueries = _db.Products.Where(x => x.User == user && !x.PrivateQuery).ToList();
db.Queries.RemoveRange(userQueries);
```

Answer (score 0):

DotNetHitMan already answered, but another option is execute a T-SQL statement:

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM Queries WHERE USER = {0} AND PrivateQuery = {1}", user, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

if User is an Id ? You are already getting a single user so do this

```
var userQueries = db.Queries.Find(x=> x.User == User && !x.PrivateQuery);

 db.Queries.Remove(userQueries);
```